# In WSL2 how can I, from the Windows side, access my \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu as case-insensitive?

Tags: wsl2

So I'm running an app on the Windows side and I want that app to access a Linux file. I see all the Linux files there at:

```
\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu
```

But the Windows app is going to use either case for any file because it's programmed for case insensitive. It never thought it would be running on a case sensitive filesystem.

So my Windows App will find file `\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\FooBar.txt` and later attempt to access file `\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\FOOBAR.TXT` then wonder why it cannot find the file it was looking for.

The solution here didn't work: [Adjust case sensitivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/case-sensitivity#case-sensitivity-options-for-mounting-a-drive-in-wsl-configuration-file). And whoever wrote it was never clear about which side was trying to access which side's file for each solution. I tried the one where you set something up in wsl.conf then reboot WSL and it did NOT allow me to access `\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\FooBar.txt` by typing `\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\FOOBAR.TXT`.

Comment: I think you'll need to copy the file to Windows.

Comment: I'll add. I tried mapping drive letter to \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\ using subst and linking a folder to it using mklink /d. Then I did the "fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo". Neither worked. But maybe if I map a network drive back to localhost that'll kill the case sensitivity.

Comment: I mean copy the entire file physically to Windows NTFS and let the app get it from there, not from WSL.

Comment: @harrymc yes I understand your suggestion but that's not what I want, hence the question.

Comment: A Windows application shouldn't care about the case of a filename. Have the Windows application perform a string operation on the filename before it's created.

Comment: @Ramhound. It's not my Windows Application it's Intellisense that doesn't work.

Comment: @JoeC - Isn’t Intellisense a feature of Visual Studio? Sounds like you should diagnose another solution since WSL2 is Linux and has all the same limitations and features.

Answer (score 1):

The article talks about making NTFS case-insensitive. You're asking for the opposite. Unfortunately, while Ext4 on Linux also supports case-insensitivity, [that's not enabled in WSL](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9849) at the moment.

One alternative is to use traditional SMB file sharing<sup>1</sup>, as the Samba SMB server on Linux has internal support for case-insensitivity even if the filesystem doesn't support that.

<sup>1</sup> (`\\wsl.localhost` uses 9P, not SMB.)

Answer (score 1):

WSL does not support
[case-insensitive file-names](https://www.collabora.com/news-and-blog/blog/2020/08/27/using-the-linux-kernel-case-insensitive-feature-in-ext4/).

The only possibility I can see is to give both names to the same file,
by creating in the Ubuntu folder a symlink named `FOOBAR.TXT` that
points to `FooBar.txt`, so both names exist and refer to the same file.

Comment: You can use string manipulation within whatever language is creating the file, to make the name of the file, all uppercase or all lowercase.

Comment: Yeah I'm actually trying to use MS Visual Studio's Intellisense which uses all capital letters as described here. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Intellisense-does-not-work-with-case-sen/1670489?space=8&q=distributing#:~:text=Intellisense forces the filesystem paths,no Intellisense assist at all.